# how to search the omnilock script code hash which deployed to CKB?

Tags: blockchain

on CKB blockchain how to search the script code deployed to CKB， for example like omnilock?

there is not enough result to show that..

Answer (score 1):

finally, I find the answer:

https://github.com/nervosnetwork/rfcs/blob/master/rfcs/0042-omnilock/0042-omnilock.md#notes

shows the code hash I want is (on test net ):
`0xf329effd1c475a2978453c8600e1eaf0bc2087ee093c3ee64cc96ec6847752cb`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).